# What can be reason that Api response can vary according to browser hit and http request

Tags: android, json, web-services, base64

I just get stuck on this I am hitting a request on Chrome its showing correct response while getting response from http request is different. I did google but didn't find something useful. Please help me, I will be very thankful..

Answer (score 0):

I encounter this problem when I was using free hosting services online.

Some of these web service implements a protection upfront.

If it is called via normal browsers, you may not notice that there is an actual redirect behind it.

HTTP Request on the other hand cannot handle the redirect. Some of these are JavaScript redirects, and that's why the result you get from HTTP request and from browser are different.

Example case :

[ByetHost server passing html values "Checking your browser" with JSON String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31912000/byethost-server-passing-html-values-checking-your-browser-with-json-string)