# org.json.JSONException: Value <html><body><script of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: java, php, android, json

I am trying to learn how to create a login and registration system for my Android App. I followed a YouTube video for that and I keep getting this error when I run my App.

Error Log:

```
06-03 14:32:14.646 2563-2563/example.login W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value <html><body><script of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
06-03 14:32:14.646 2563-2563/example.login W/System.err:     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
06-03 14:32:14.646 2563-2563/example.login W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:160)
06-03 14:32:14.646 2563-2563/example.login W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:173)
06-03 14:32:14.646 2563-2563/example.login W/System.err:     at vipanchithreddy.login.RegisterActivity$1$1.onResponse(RegisterActivity.java:41)
06-03 14:32:14.646 2563-2563/example.login W/System.err:     at vipanchithreddy.login.RegisterActivity$1$1.onResponse(RegisterActivity.java:37)
06-03 14:32:14.647 2563-2563/example.login W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:60)
06-03 14:32:14.647 2563-2563/example.login W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:30)
06-03 14:32:14.647 2563-2563/example.login W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
06-03 14:32:14.647 2563-2563/example.login W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
06-03 14:32:14.647 2563-2563/example.login W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
06-03 14:32:14.647 2563-2563/example.login W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
06-03 14:32:14.647 2563-2563/example.login W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
06-03 14:32:14.647 2563-2563/example.login W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
06-03 14:32:14.647 2563-2563/example.login W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
06-03 14:32:14.647 2563-2563/example.login W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

I am new to JSON encoding. I read many threads regarding this problem, but still no clue on how to solve it. These are my php and java files.

Register.php:

```
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect("my_server", "my_user", "my_password", "my_database");

    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];
    $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO user (username, password) VALUES (?, ?)");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ss", $username, $password);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

    $response = array();
    $response["success"] = true;

    echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

RegisterRequest.java:

```
package example.login;

import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class RegisterRequest extends StringRequest {
    private static final String REGISTER_REQUEST_URL = "http://www.vipanchith.byethost17.com/file/Register.php";
    private Map<String, String> params;

    public RegisterRequest(String username, String password, Response.Listener<String> listener) {
        super(Method.POST, REGISTER_REQUEST_URL, listener, null);
        params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("username", username);
        params.put("password", password);
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getParams() {
        return params;
    }
}
```

RegisterActivity.java:

```
package example.login;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        final EditText etUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
        final EditText etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);

        final Button bRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bRegister);

        assert bRegister != null;
        bRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final String username = etUsername.getText().toString();
                final String password = etPassword.getText().toString();

                Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                            boolean success = jsonResponse.getBoolean("success");

                            if (success) {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                                RegisterActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                            } else {
                                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(RegisterActivity.this);
                                builder.setMessage("Registration Failed")
                                        .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                                        .create()
                                        .show();
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                };

                RegisterRequest registerRequest = new RegisterRequest(username, password, responseListener);
                RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(RegisterActivity.this);
                queue.add(registerRequest);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: you can print your response content before parsing to json. I think maybe it is a error page html code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you guys, there is no problem with the code. This is an extra protection that has been added deliberately by byethost.com to block bots from accessing our sites resulting in huge security benefits to our scripts. I reuploaded these files into 000webhost.com and it worked like a charm.
For further information, refer this discussion
[ByetHost server passing html values "Checking your browser" with JSON String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31912000/byethost-server-passing-html-values-checking-your-browser-with-json-string)

Answer (score 0):

This error occurred if the json what you get if it has values.

```
{
   test:[
    {
       id:1,
       name:me
   },
  {
   id:2,
   name:you
 }
]
}
```

And if json has no value...

```
{

}
```

...then that error occurred.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but how do i check if json has no value?

Comment: You need to modify web service api . Web api structure must be same.