# ByetHost issue when retriving json using httpclient work only with wifi

Tags: javascript, android, json, httpclient

Following the solution in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31912000/byethost-server-passing-html-values-checking-your-browser-with-json-string) 
HttpClient works only when connected with wifi. when connected with cell notwork ByetHost server reply with "This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in your browser or use a browser with Javascript support".