# The content of cookie changed after a day

Tags: android, nginx

I create a login system for my android app and I get this error:

```
org.json.JSONException: Value <html><body><script of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

I solved this problem with [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40684122/9422637) and override my `getHeader()` method like this:

```
class JsonArrayRequest1 extends JsonArrayRequest {
    private static final String KEY_COOKIE = "Cookie";
    private static final String VALUE_CONTENT = "__test=641d2ca6fcd49bad844a6d51bc3f7566; path=/";

    public JsonArrayRequest1(int get, String s, Object o, Response.Listener<JSONArray> listener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
        super(get, s, null, listener, errorListener);
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
        Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>(); 
         headers.put(KEY_COOKIE, VALUE_CONTENT);
        return headers;
    }
}
```

This solution return the true result. After a day, the content value of `testcookie-nginx-module` cookie changed. Thus the result is `null`.

`testcookie-nginx-module` is a simple security antibots

This is detail of `testcookie-nginx-module` in Opera browser:

[image: cookie detail]

Now the question is:
 **Is it possible to keep the content value of `testcookie-nginx-module` cookie the same?** or **Is there best way to get true result after changing `testcookie-nginx-module` content?**

Comment: So if client request contains a certain cookie value you want server to allow access, and you don't want that value to keep changing?