# android update photo to server error: this site requires Javascript to work

Tags: php, android, mysql

My question is about the script below:

[image]

I saw this question [ByetHost server passing html values "Checking your browser" with JSON String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31912000/byethost-server-passing-html-values-checking-your-browser-with-json-string) at StackOverflow,
but I don't know how can I change my java. Please help me. I use free `vistapanel`.

php

```html
<?php

 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
 
 $image = $_POST['image'];
 
 require_once('UploadToServer.php');
 
 $sql = "INSERT INTO images  VALUES (?)";
 
 $stmt = mysqli_prepare($con,$sql);
 
 mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"s",$image);
 mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
 
 $check = mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt);
 
 if($check == 1){
 echo "Image Uploaded Successfully";

 }else{
 echo "Error Uploading Image";

 }
 mysqli_close($con);
 
 }else{
 echo "Error";

 }
 exit();
 ?>
```

Here is my android

```
public class RequestHandler {

    public String sendGetRequest(String uri) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(uri);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

            String result;

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            while((result = bufferedReader.readLine())!=null){
                sb.append(result);
            }

            return sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public String sendPostRequest(String requestURL,
                                  HashMap<String, String> postDataParams) {

        URL url;
        String response = "";
        try {
            url = new URL(requestURL);

            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(15000);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);

            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(getPostDataString(postDataParams));

            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            os.close();
            int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();

            if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                response = br.readLine();
            } else {
                response = "Error Registering";
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return response;
    }

    private String getPostDataString(HashMap<String, String> params) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        boolean first = true;
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()) {
            if (first)
                first = false;
            else
                result.append("&");

            result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
            result.append("=");
            result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
        }

        return result.toString();
    }
}
```

Here is my Main

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

public static final String UPLOAD_URL = "http://ksuwork.byethost16.com/upload.php";
public static final String UPLOAD_KEY = "image";
public static final String TAG = "MY MESSAGE";

private int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 1;

private Button buttonChoose;
private Button buttonUpload;
private Button buttonView;
private ImageView imageView;

private Bitmap bitmap;

private Uri filePath;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    buttonChoose = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonChoose);
    buttonUpload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonUpload);
    buttonView = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonViewImage);

    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    buttonChoose.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonUpload.setOnClickListener(this);
}

private void showFileChooser() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {

        filePath = data.getData();
        try {
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public String getStringImage(Bitmap bmp){
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
    byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
    String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
    return encodedImage;
}

private void uploadImage(){
    class UploadImage extends AsyncTask<Bitmap,Void,String>{

        ProgressDialog loading;
        RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler();

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            loading = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Uploading Image", "Please wait...",true,true);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            loading.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),s,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Bitmap... params) {
            Bitmap bitmap = params[0];
            String uploadImage = getStringImage(bitmap);

            HashMap<String,String> data = new HashMap<>();
            data.put(UPLOAD_KEY, uploadImage);

            String result = rh.sendPostRequest(UPLOAD_URL,data);

            return result;
        }
    }

    UploadImage ui = new UploadImage();
    ui.execute(bitmap);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v == buttonChoose) {
        showFileChooser();
    }
    if(v == buttonUpload){
        uploadImage();
    }
}
}
```

Sorry for the long post, but I feel it would be almost redundant to ask a question without providing enough information to have a chance at solving it. Thanks for anyone who takes their time out to help!

Comment: Please never your code as image, much better is add code in code block.

Comment: Your problem is in Server Side and you have the same problem like me . See below post on SO for more information.
[Android Error: This site requires Javascript to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59511799/android-error-this-site-requires-javascript-to-work/59519144#59519144)