# This site requires Javascript enabled in your browser

Tags: javascript, android, rest, server

I Need to download some files from Server
I use **Retrofit** ,**Voelly** and **DownLoadManager** which are some of ways to download files from server in android , but my response is not the things that I want .

I test my app with other URLs from other servers and it works perfectly.

When I test my app with my Host I get below Response From Server as HTML File.

> This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in your 
>   browser or use a browser with Javascript support

I also test my download URl from My server in browsers and it returns the true file .

What is the problem with my server ???

> My complete response

```html
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/aes.js" >
</script>

<script>
function toNumbers(d){
  var e=[];
  d.replace(/(..)/g,function(d){e.push(parseInt(d,16))});
  return e
}

function toHex(){

  for(var d=[],d=1==arguments.length&&
  arguments[0].constructor==Array?arguments[0]:arguments,e="",
  f=0; f<d.length;f++)
     e+=(16>d[f]?"0":"")+d[f].toString(16);

 return e.toLowerCase()
}

var a=toNumbers("f655ba9d09a112d4968c63579db590b4"),
b=toNumbers("98344c2eee86c3994890592585b49f80"),
c=toNumbers("4e617cfaefcd0f6f4fea87d72b611efa");

document.cookie="__test="+toHex(slowAES.decrypt(c,2,a,b))+";
 expires=Thu, 31-Dec-37 23:55:55 GMT; path=/"; 
location.href="http://<myURL>/sang.epub?i=1";
   </script>

<noscript>
This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in your 

browser or use a browser with Javascript support
</noscript>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After getting a response from my host support team, I found that the problem is from **Server Side**. I have used the free hosting.

Support Team said to me that their free hosts are only for creating websites and not downloading files from them.

I think this is for be [Scraping](https://www.parsehub.com/blog/what-is-web-scraping/) **disabled** or maybe not having **SSL**.

I finally used better free **host provider** which allows me to download files from server and send request from android client.
My new Host Provider: [www.000webhost.com](http://www.000webhost.com)

Comment: This actually was the answer for me. I was using InfinityFree for testing and switching to 000webhost had it working immediately.

Comment: Oh, I am doing InfinityFree also I get this error. I will change too.