# How to send data from SIM900 HTTP GET to mySQL database (75% there?)

Tags: php, mysql, arduino, sim900

Thanks for taking time to read my post. Ill try just cover what i believe to be important to the problem but i'm not a professional coder so please bear with me.

I have a SIM900 module with an Arduino Mega, and am trying to use the http get function to send data to a mySQL database. I have successfully used the SIM900 to create text files in my .ftp server so i know it works to some degree, just not the http function. I have a .php script which works fine when i use it through my browser (eg. visiting "mysite.epizy.com/senddata.php?sensor69=69" will return in the browser:

> Array ( [sensor69] => 69 [__test] => dfc33491ff131abef9348da81e436528 [_ga] => GA1.2.428043981.1572933465 )

When i try connect with the SIM900 i get the following on my serial:

```
    setting connection type
AT+SAPBR=3,1,"CONTYPE","GPRS"

OK

AT+SAPBR=3,1,"APN","WWW.vodafone.net.nz"

OK

AT+SAPBR=1,1

ERROR

AT+SAPBR=2,1

+SAPBR: 1,1,"121.90.164.49"

OK

AT+HTTPINIT

OK

AT+HTTPPARA="CID",1

OK

AT+HTTPPARA="URL","mysite.epizy.com/send_data.php?sensor69=69"



OK

AT+HTTPACTION=0

OK
⸮⸮

+HTTPACTION:0,200,859
⸮
AT+HTTPREAD

+HTTPREAD:859
<html><body><script type="text/javascript" src="/aes.js" ></script><script>function toNumbers(d){var e=[];d.replace(/(..)/g,function(d){e.push(parseInt(d,16))});return e}function toHex(){for(var d=[],d=1==arguments.length&&ar
AT+HTTPTERM

OK
```

As we can see on the HTTPREAD function returns 859 characters but this seems to be truncated, and there is no registration in my database or log file (created/updated within the .php)
This is my .php script "senddata.php"

```
<?php

print_r($_REQUEST);

    //log php activation
 

date_default_timezone_set("Pacific/Auckland");

$my_file = 'log.txt';
$handle = fopen($my_file, 'a') or die('Cannot open file:  '.$my_file);
$new_data = "\n"."Module=".$_GET['moduleID'].", ". date("d:m:Y")." ". date("h/i/sa");
fwrite($handle, $new_data);
fclose($handle);

// Prepare variables for database connection
    $dbusername = "epiz_69696969";  // enter database username, I used "arduino" in step 2.2
    $dbpassword = "69696969696969";  // enter database password, I used "arduinotest" in step 2.2
    $server = "sql169.epizy.com"; // IMPORTANT: if you are using XAMPP enter "localhost", but if you have an online website enter its address, ie."www.yourwebsite.com"


    $moduleID=$_GET['moduleID'];

    // Connect to your database

    $dbconnect = mysql_pconnect($server, $dbusername, $dbpassword);
    $dbselect = mysql_select_db("epiz_24743320_testData",$dbconnect);

    // Prepare the SQL statement

    $sql = "INSERT INTO simData2 (moduleID) VALUES ('$moduleID')";


    // Execute SQL statement

    mysql_query($sql);
    mysql_close();

?>
```

Here is the section of my arduino code for the http connect:

```
void httpConnect() {
 
    myGsm.println("AT+SAPBR=3,1,\"CONTYPE\",\"GPRS\""); // Set type of internet connection to GPRS context
    delay(1000);
    Serial.println(" setting connection type");
    printSerialData();
    myGsm.println("AT+SAPBR=3,1,\"APN\",\"WWW.vodafone.net.nz\""); // Set access point name
    delay(1000);
    printSerialData();
    myGsm.println("AT+SAPBR=1,1"); // Enable GPRS connection
    delay(1000);
    printSerialData();
    myGsm.println("AT+SAPBR=2,1");  // To check connection status
    delay(5000);
    printSerialData();
    
    myGsm.println("AT+HTTPINIT");                  // Initialize HTTP
    delay(500);
    printSerialData();
    myGsm.println("AT+HTTPPARA=\"CID\",1");    // End the PARA ???
    delay(500);
    printSerialData();
    
    myGsm.print("AT+HTTPPARA=\"URL\",\"mysite.epizy.com/send_data.php?sen69=69\""); // Send PARA command, set url to send data
        
            
    
    
           delay(2000);
    printSerialData();
       delay(2000);
    printSerialData();
    myGsm.println("");   // close url
    Serial.println("");
    delay(500);
    printSerialData();
    delay(500);
    myGsm.println("AT+HTTPACTION=0"); //HTTP method 0-get 1-post 2-head
    delay(1000);
    printSerialData();
        delay(1000);
    printSerialData();
        delay(2000);
    printSerialData();
            delay(2000);
    printSerialData();
            delay(2000);
    printSerialData();
    myGsm.println("AT+HTTPREAD");
            delay(2000);
    printSerialData();
        delay(2000);
    printSerialData();
            delay(2000);
    printSerialData();
    myGsm.println("AT+HTTPTERM");
    delay(100); 
    printSerialData();     

}
```

If anyone can help shed light on why the SIM900 module is not working to activate my .php at all any help would be so greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: It does not only seem truncated, but something completely different than what your PHP code should return - I am not seeing any `<script type="text/javascript" src="/aes.js" ></script><script>function toNumbers(d) …` in there. I’d start by checking access and error log of the web server where you have the PHP running, and see what those requests look like.

Comment: Actually, those scripts appear to be from some “bot detection” functionality, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31912000/byethost-server-passing-html-values-checking-your-browser-with-json-string

Comment: **Warning:** `mysql_*` extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and has been removed as of PHP 7.0.0. Instead, either the [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) extension should be used. See also the [MySQL API Overview](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for further help while choosing a MySQL API.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue. It turns out the server i was using (epizy.com (infinity free)) requires javascript capabilities which the SIM900 does not have (in my current setup at least).
I have created a new server with heroku, using pretty much the same .php file (database is postgreSQL not mySQL so some small tweaks) and am now successfully sending data into the database as i require. I still have not resolved the truncating serial responses but this is not necessary for the functionality i'm after.