# Xamarin.Android - How to get JSON from website

Tags: json, xamarin, xamarin.android

I want to get JSON data from Site

Nothing shows up about it and Xamarin and I tried these 3 from youtube and it didn't work for me

```
        public void ValidateNumber()
        {
            string URL = "http://android-householdinventory-api.epizy.com/ValidateNumber.php?";
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            Uri uri = new Uri(URL + "number=10");
            client.DownloadDataAsync(uri);
            client.DownloadDataCompleted += Client_DownloadDataCompleted;
        }

        private void Client_DownloadDataCompleted(object sender, DownloadDataCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
            string json = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e.Result);
            System.Console.WriteLine(json);
        }

        public async void Validationv2()
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var uri = "http://android-householdinventory-api.epizy.com/ValidateNumber.php?number=100";
                var Result = await client.GetStringAsync(uri);
                System.Console.WriteLine(Result);
            }
        }

        public void Validationv3()
        {
            WebClient wclient = new WebClient();
            string a = wclient.DownloadString("http://android-householdinventory-api.epizy.com/ValidateNumber.php?number=100");
            System.Console.WriteLine(a);
        }
```

All Results to this:

```
<html><body><script type="text/javascript" src="/aes.js" ></script><script>function toNumbers(d){var e=[];d.replace(/(..)/g,function(d){e.push(parseInt(d,16))});return e}function toHex(){for(var d=[],d=1==arguments.length&&arguments[0].constructor==Array?arguments[0]:arguments,e="",f=0;f<d.length;f++)e+=(16>d[f]?"0":"")+d[f].toString(16);return e.toLowerCase()}var a=toNumbers("f655ba9d09a112d4968c63579db590b4"),b=toNumbers("98344c2eee86c3994890592585b49f80"),c=toNumbers("304feeb55638873348a9f20961a94049");document.cookie="__test="+toHex(slowAES.decrypt(c,2,a,b))+"; expires=Thu, 31-Dec-37 23:55:55 GMT; path=/"; location.href="http://android-householdinventory-api.epizy.com/ValidateNumber.php?number=10&i=1";</script><noscript>This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in your browser or use a browser with Javascript support</noscript></body></html>
```

How to fix this?

I'm new to c# and Xamarin

Comment: Use `HttpClient` instead of `WebClient` : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=xamarinandroid-7.1

Comment: @SushiHangover I tried HttpClient but same results, 
        public async void Validationv2()
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var uri = "http://android-householdinventory-api.epizy.com/ValidateNumber.php?number=100";
                var Result = await client.GetStringAsync(uri);
                System.Console.WriteLine(Result);
            }
        }
Am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your API server is returning HTML response for this "http://android-householdinventory-api.epizy.com/ValidateNumber.php?number=100" end point that's why it is showing HTML in response. You will have to correct the api response on server side.

Answer (score 0):

try this! working example

```
private async void btn_Login_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
 List<LoginDetails> UserDetails = await _services.LoginAsync(string username,    string password)
 }




  public async Task<List<LoginDetails>> LoginAsync(string username, string password)
    {
        List<LoginDetails> UserList;
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            LoginDetails Ld = new LoginDetails();
            Ld.UserName = username;
            Ld.Password = password;
            string url = "";
            //HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            string jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Ld);
            StringContent content = new StringContent(jsonData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(url, content);
            string result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();


            UserList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<LoginDetails>>(result);
            //loginDetails = new ObservableCollection<LoginDetails>(UserList);
        }
        return UserList;

    }
```

Comment: I'll try it, by the way, do I need to pass json data?

Comment: Yes, StringContent content = new StringContent(jsonData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");, You can use postman to pass data and check response.

Answer (score 0):

I was hosting on InfinityFree and it has aes.js so it may be causing that result.

This helped me in getting the solution

[Setting Authorization Header of HttpClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14627399/setting-authorization-header-of-httpclient)
[ByetHost server passing html values "Checking your browser" with JSON String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31912000/byethost-server-passing-html-values-checking-your-browser-with-json-string)

[I added this before client.GetAsync]
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Cookie", "__test=<COOKIE_CONTENT>; expires=<COOKIE_EXPIRATION>; path=/");