# Enable js response when trying to exexute a php file from cron-job.org

Tags: javascript, cron

I have a php file in a free server (byethost) that I want to be executed from cron-job.org, but I am reciving a no script js response. Ideas how to fixed will be worth. Thanks

Response:

```
Server: nginx
Date: Wed, 24 Nov 2021 21:09:29 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 848
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache

<html>

<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/aes.js"></script>
    <script>function toNumbers(d) { var e = []; d.replace(/(..)/g, function (d) { e.push(parseInt(d, 16)) }); return e } function toHex() { for (var d = [], d = 1 == arguments.length && arguments[0].constructor == Array ? arguments[0] : arguments, e = "", f = 0; f < d.length; f++)e += (16 > d[f] ? "0" : "") + d[f].toString(16); return e.toLowerCase() } var a = toNumbers("f655ba9d09a112d4968c63579db590b4"), b = toNumbers("98344c2eee86c3994890592585b49f80"), c = toNumbers("d61ae965428c82887a530079c50d1343"); document.cookie = "__test=" + toHex(slowAES.decrypt(c, 2, a, b)) + "; expires=Thu, 31-Dec-37 23:55:55 GMT; path=/"; location.href = "myUrl";</script>
    <noscript>This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in your browser or use a browser with
        Javascript support</noscript>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "a no script js response", and where are you recieving it? What did you expect to see?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is a [limitation of the free host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31912000/byethost-server-passing-html-values-checking-your-browser-with-json-string)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).