# Bing refuses to index my blog when I submit a url it returns: "This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in your browser..."

Tags: php, wordpress, indexing, httpresponse, search-engine-bots

I believe my problem is very much related to the one answered here.  [ByetHost server passing html values "Checking your browser" with JSON String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31912000/byethost-server-passing-html-values-checking-your-browser-with-json-string/45409278#45409278).  Every time I try to get Bing to Index my site it fails and when I check in webmaster tools for my site the live url always returns this:

````
```
Cache-Control : no-cache
Date : Sun, 22 Jan 2023 13:19:11 GMT
Content-Type : text/html
Content-Encoding : gzip
Expires : Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT
Server : LiteSpeed
Vary : Accept-Encoding
x-litespeed-tag : 460_
x-qc-pop : NA-US-PDX-277
alt-svc : h3=":443"; ma=2592000, h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000, h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000, h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000, h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000, quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="43,46"

This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in your browser or use a browser with Javascript support
<html><body><script type="text/javascript" src="/aes.js" ></script><script>function toNumbers(d){var e=[];d.replace(/(..)/g,function(d){e.push(parseInt(d,16))});return e}function toHex(){for(var d=[],d=1==arguments.length&&arguments[0].constructor==Array?arguments[0]:arguments,e="",f=0;f<d.length;f++)e+=(16>d[f]?"0":"")+d[f].toString(16);return e.toLowerCase()}var a=toNumbers("f655ba9d09a112d4968c63579db590b4"),b=toNumbers("98344c2eee86c3994890592585b49f80"),c=toNumbers("d36f42cf611c2d9cd780e0477a942765");document.cookie="__test="+toHex(slowAES.decrypt(c,2,a,b))+"; expires=Thu, 31-Dec-37 23:55:55 GMT; path=/"; location.href="https://diygamecontrollers.ml/?i=1";</script><noscript>This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in your browser or use a browser with Javascript support</noscript></body></html>
```
````

From what I gather in the StackOverflow post I linked above is that this is all because of some anti robots module that byethost runs on their servers called the "testcookie-nginx-module."

In the application the poster was asking about a workaround was to simply add "`exit();`" to the end of a .php file at the last executable statement.  I'm hoping doing the same to some .php file on my server could accomplish the same thing?  Maybe "index.php" or "load.php"?  I'd prefer not to try and do this by trial and error if possible?  Also I'm using wordpress if that matters at all?

The strangest thing is that Google can index posts and pages on my site just fine but it flat out refuses to accept my .xml sitemap.  While Bing accepts all my sitemaps without issue but refuses to index any of the links therein.  I'm thinking these problems must be related right?  I've got a firefox extension that lets me view pages as if I was googlebot but I haven't found anything that would let me impersonate bingbot, not that it has proven particularly useful up until now.

The site is https://diygamecontrollers.ml if you need to check it out or anything?  If there is anything else you need from me please let me know I'm going to turn notifications on in this post so I should be pretty quick to respond.

Thank you all so much in advance.

## **Update**

I now know of over a dozen files which adding `exit();` to will not make your site indexable by Bing or your sitemap fetchable by Google.  I turned off CloudFlare but there is still a slight chance that the spiders were being fed a cached version of my pages from somewhere else so confirming my results wouldn't be a complete waste of time.

The files I edited to add `exit();` to the very end of were:

### *In .htdocs*

- wp-blog-header.php

### In ./wp/includes

- http.php,
- load.php
- rewrite.php
- script-loader.php
- session.php
- sitemaps.php
- default-constants.php
- embed.php
- formatting.php
- functions.php
- functions.wp-scripts.php

Interestingly the only one that took my site offline for web browsers was near the end when I modified 'Sitemaps.php'.  That change threw both Edge and Firefox into "quirks mode" where all they would render was a blank white page.  Naturally that was the last change I undid because I thought that one was the safest of the lot!?

Comment: The answer you are referring to with the `exit` has zero upvotes or comments, so it is hard to say if it would work without trying. I know you probably won’t like this, but a host doing things to your HTTP stream without you being able to stop them (without resorting to hacky things) isn’t a good host, at least for anything of consequence, and you should probably consider looking elsewhere.

Comment: @chrishaas You certainly have a point, although they offer unlimited bandwidth and 5 or 10 gigs of storage on their free plan so I can understand why they'd want to prevent people using their service as a backend for some app or who knows what type of file hosting.  The fact that there isn't some one click solution so that Bing can index you is still total bs.